# Position Element in HTML Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a little star icon in certain cells of a table and I want to position it in the top right corner. So here's my html:

```
<td>Cell_Text<div class="star">☆</div></td>
```

How do I position the all stars with a table cell in the top right hand corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
div.star
{
 float:right;
 margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Else you can use absolute, but in your case i am not sure

```
div.star
{
position:absolute;
top:somepx;
right:somepx;
}
```

Comment: ah worked like a charm. Any ideas on how to fill the star with a certain color?

Comment: if * is a text , you can add another property Color:orange in div.star block.

Comment: Yah i did that but that only colored the borders. I guess I need to get a pre-filled star or something?

Comment: better remove the text and use some small star as background image, by setting background:url(images/star.png') no-repeat;

Answer (score 1):

Use relative + absolute positioning

```
td { position: relative; }
td .star { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
td {
    /* required in order to position the element relative to the cell */
    position: relative;
}

td .star {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U8Kme/).

References:

- [CSS Position, at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position).

Answer (score 0):

you may simply use

```
float:right;
```

in your css. Just make sure that the size of the icon is relatively smaller than that of cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make the star as superscript to the text

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Wg7Vv/)

I have used ascii code instead of the star you are using. 
You can also use unicode in it.

The plus point of using this approach is that you can color them by using the below property

```
color: /* your desired color */
```